# Multiple listeners created but only the last responding

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm creating multiple click events on a bunch of dynamically generated LI elements. But when I click any of them only the last li's event is dispatched.

It's a little hard to explain but here's a fiddle that will make things more clear:

http://jsfiddle.net/5uecp/2/

...and the code:

```
// Parent Class
function Parent(id, children) {
  this.id = id;
  this.children = children;
  this.init();
}

Parent.prototype = {

  init: function () {
    this.addEventHanlders()
  },

  addEventHanlders: function () {

    addEventListener('childEvent', function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation()
      // console.log('childEvent', e.title)
    });

  },

  render: function () {

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.setAttribute('id', this.id)

    for (var i = this.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      ul.appendChild(this.children[i].render());
    };

    document.body.appendChild(ul);
  }
}

// Child Class
function Child(title) {
  this.title = title;
  this.li = null
  this.event = document.createEvent("Event");

};

Child.prototype = {

  render: function () {
    _this = this;
    this.li = document.createElement('li');
    text = document.createTextNode(this.title);
    a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', '#');
    a.appendChild(text);
    this.li.appendChild(a);
    this.li.setAttribute('class', 'child');

    this.li.addEventListener('click', this.clickEventHandler, true);

    return this.li;
  },

  clickEventHandler: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    _this.changeColor();
    _this.fireEvent();
    e.target.removeEventListener('click', this.clickEventHandler)
  },

  changeColor: function (color) {
    color = color || 'red';
    this.li.style.backgroundColor = color;

  },

  fireEvent: function () {
    console.log('fireEvent', this.title);
    this.event.initEvent("childEvent", true, true);
    this.event.title = this.title;
    document.dispatchEvent(this.event);
  }
};

// Initialize
children = [new Child("Child 1"), new Child("Child 2"), new Child("Child 3"), new Child("Child 4"), new Child("Child 5")]
parent = new Parent("parent", children)

$(function () {
  parent.render();
});
```

Comment: It does seem like a really bad idea to not use jQuery for the event handlers, as that is one of the things it's truly great for, when you're already using it for the DOM ready event ?

Comment: Ya, would agree but I'm trying to get my head around the event mondel in js. Don't want to cheat with jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are saving `this` into the global variable `_this`, that is accessible from everywhere. As a result you've got the link to the last `Child` instance in `_this`.

See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/5uecp/4/

Comment: Ahh... I'm a dummy. I didn't use the 'var' keyword when I create `_this`. Thanks Llya